# How to change specific href attribute with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element that I want to change in my page with jQuery:

```
<a class="table-cell" title="Affordable Loan Solution™ Mortgage" href="/en/articles/affordable-loan-solution-mortgage.html" name="affordableloansolutionmortgage_image_topicgrid">

  <span class="linkwidth"> Affordable Loan Solution™ Mortgage </span>
  <img alt="Affordable Loan Solution™ Mortgage" src="/res/img/topic/article.gif">

</a>
```

I want to change that href which is automatically generated and put this instead:

`https://www.bankofamerica.com/mortgage/`

what can I do in this case?

Comment: `$('[name="affordableloansolutionmortgage_image_topicgrid"]').attr('href','https://www.bankofamerica.com/mortgage/')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get element using name attribute with help of [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) and update `href` attribute using [`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) method.

```
$('[name="affordableloansolutionmortgage_image_topicgrid"]').attr('href','https:‌​//www.bankofamerica.‌​com/mortgage/');
// or using class selector
$('.table-cell').attr('href','https:‌​//www.bankofamerica.‌​com/mortgage/');
```

Comment: I am getting an error with the 1st solution: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer :  I just updated.. it happened because the previous string contains some invalid characters